# C# Enums...and user inputs

Tags: c#, enums

So my project is to create an enum with the planets, Mecury through Neptune(1-8) for their enum variables. My Book is about 2 pages on Enums and isn't being much for use.

I have to create a program that with an Enum labeled Planets...such as follows

```
enum Planet
{
    Mercury = 1, Venus, Earth, Mars, Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus, Neptune
}
```

and prompting the user for an input of a number, 1-8 will display which planet is in that position in the Enum.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    System.Console.WriteLine("What Planet Are You Looking For? 1-8? ");
    string planet1 = System.Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I've tried about 3 variations, and all are giving me nothing of what I need, I can display the name, but not at the user input. So I've gone back to scratch.

Comment: 1 through 9. I suggest you refuse to submit the assignment until the teacher recants the heretical and preposterous notion that Pluto is not a planet. The principle at stake here is far more important than a mere grade.

Comment: @EdPlunkett it's probably to prevent similar issues to what we have now with time zones, since you'd have to handle the cases where Pluto became the eighth planet. https://starchild.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/StarChild/questions/question5.html

Comment: I'll add it in on my own since Pluto IS a planet!

Comment: Have you tried searching google in order to find better resources than said book? I got very nice results by searching for "C# enum".

Comment: @ps2goat Cool, it's like Y2k all over again! But unless Damian takes a really, really long time to finish his degree, he's probably safe.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: aye, aye! Just because it was (possibly) a big moon once long ago, doesn't mean it's not a planet now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this doesn't handle parameter switches properly nor handle errors appropriately, here's one way of basically doing this. Let us know how this works out for you. :)

```
System.Console.WriteLine("What Planet Are You Looking For? 1-8? ");
string planet1 = System.Console.ReadLine();

Planet planet = (Planet)Convert.ToInt32(planet1);

System.Console.WriteLine(planet);
```

Comment: How does this answer account for an input of `"foo"`? Or any other non-numeric input?

Comment: you are correct, that's why I stated it does not appropriately handle parameters or errors.  It was just conceptual in nature.

Answer (score 4):

You can very simply cast the int to the enum like so:

```
if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int planetNum))
{
    if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Planet), planetNum)
    {
        Planet myPlanet = (Planet)planetNum;
    }
}
```

You'll notice two checks are performed: We use [`TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) to check if the user has entered a valid integer, and [`Enum.IsDefined`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined.aspx) to ensure that the integer they have entered corresponds to a planet in the enum.

*Alternatively*, if you would like to have the user enter the names of the planets instead of numbers, you can use [`Enum.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Enum.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out Planet planet1);
```

Answer (score 1):

BenGalluzzo

You nailed it on the head

and for everyone else...I did add Pluto.

Thanks everyone!

Here's the final code!

```
class Program
{
    enum Planet
    {
        Mercury = 1, Venus, Earth, Mars, Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus, Neptune, Pluto
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("What Planet Are You Looking For? Pluto is a planet! 1-9? ");
        string planet1 = System.Console.ReadLine();

        Planet planet = (Planet)Convert.ToInt32(planet1);

        System.Console.WriteLine(planet);


        System.Console.WriteLine();


        System.Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Ok So are the users supposed to just implictly know that you are expecting the planets to be in the order from the sun?  What happens when Uranus and Neptune switch places...

Comment: @maccettura Most people will assume my-very-early-mother order.

Comment: @EdPlunkett you are probably right, but it wouldnt hurt to have the planet name associated with the input option number.  Its a good learning opportunity for a baby dev

Comment: @maccettura True enough.

Comment: Also, I think its Pluto and Neptune that switch.  Not Uranus and Neptune.  Its been a while though

Comment: @maccettura Pluto and Neptune definitely switch; looks like Uranus stays in his own lane: https://starchild.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/StarChild/questions/question5.html

Comment: Oh it looks like someone already mentioned that in the OP comments.  I should spent more time reading these posts, hahaha

Answer (score 0):

Convert to string and then cast to enum.

```
(Planet)int.Parse(planet1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a menu for the user, so its easier to see all the options:

```
Console.WriteLine("What Planet Are You Looking For? 1-8? ");
foreach (Planet planet in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Planet)))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}). {1}", (int)planet, planet.ToString());
}
```

Then try to parse the input as an int

```
int planetInput = 0;
if(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out planetInput))
{
    //Successfully parsed
    //Now see if its part of your enum
    if(Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Planet), planetInput))
    {
        Planet selectedPlanet = (Planet)value; 
    }    
}
```